# Event sourcing combinded with deletable data

Tags: blob, domain-driven-design

I want to develop an `Emailer` microservice which provides a `SendEmail` command. Inside the microservice I have an aggregate in mind which represents the whole email process with the following events:

Aggregate `Email`:

- (`EmailCreated`)
- `EmailDeliveryStarted`
- `EmailDeliveryFailed`
- `EmailRecipientDelivered` when one of the recipients received the email
- `EmailRecipientDeliveryFailed` when one of the recipients could not receive the email
- etc.

In the background the email delivery service [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) is used; my microservice works like a facade for that with my own events. The incoming webhooks from SendGrid are translated to proper domain events.

The process would look like this:

1. Command `SendEmail` ==> `EmailCreated`
2. `EmailCreatedHandler` ==> Email.`Send` (to SendGrid)
3. Incoming webhook ==> `EmailDeliveryStarted`
4. Further webhooks ==> `EmailRecipientDelivered`, `EmailRecipientDeliveryFailed`, etc.

Of course if I'd want to replace the external webservice and it would apply other messaging strategies I would adapt to that but keep my domain model with it's events. I want to let the client not worry about the concrete email delivery strategy.

Now the crucial problem I face: I want to accept the `SendEmail` commands even if SendGrid is not available at that very moment, which entails storing the whole email data (with attachments) and then, with an event handler, start the sending process. On the other hand I don't want to bloat my initial `EmailCreated` event with this BLOB data. And I want to be able to clean up this data after SendGrid has accepted my send email request.

I could also try both sending the email to SendGrid and storing an initial `EmailDeliveryStarted` event in the `SendEmail` command. But this feels like a two-phase commit: if SendGrid accepted my call but somehow my repository was unable to store the `EmailDeliveryStarted` event the client would be informed that something went wrong and it tries again which would be a disaster.

So I don't know how to design my aggregate and, more important, my `EmailCreated` event since it should not contain the BLOB data like attachments.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question interesting and it took a little bit to reflect on that.

First things first - I do not see an obligation to store the email attachments in the event. You can simply store the fully qualified name of the files attached. That would keep the event log smaller and perhaps rule out the need for "deleting" the event (and you know that, in an event source model, you should not do that).

Secondly, assuming that the project is not building an e-mail client, I don't see a need to model an e-mail as an aggregate root. I see AggregateRoots represent business-relevant domains, not for a utility task like sending an e-mail. You could model this far more easily using a database table / document that keeps track of what has been sent and what not yet. I see sending e-mails through SendGrid as a reaction to a business event, certainly to be tracked, but not an AggregateRoot in its own right.

Lastly, if you want to accept `SendEmail` commands also when SendGrid is offline, the aggregate emits an `EmailQueued` event. The `EmailQueuedHandler` will produce a line on the read model of the process in charge taking all the Emails in queued state and batch them for sending. If the communication with SendGrid fails, you can either:

- Do nothing, the sender process will pick the email at the next attempt
- Emit a `EmailSendFailed`, intercepted by a `Handler` that will increase the retry count (if you want to stop after a number of retries).

Hope that is sufficiently clear and best of luck with your project.